# Orc racial traits: Menacing and Aggressive, how do they work?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm trying to create a Barbarian Orc character since the Orc was introduced into Volo's guide to Monsters.

I just don't seem to understand correctly on how these 2 traits work: **Aggressive** and **Menacing**.

**Aggressive:**
As a bonus action, you can move up to your speed toward an enemy of your choice that you can see or hear. You must end this move closer to the enemy than you started.

I don't quite understand this part in which it says. *You must end this move closer to the enemy than you started* it sounds it is not very good explained, are they trying to say that you have to end this move at 5 feet of the enemy, otherwise you cannot use this as a bonus action?

2 questions here:
Let's say that an enemy casts Darkness and then that it does rest into the darkness AoE, if I for example make a ready so that when I hear him breathe, and because I've heard him, can I use the **Aggressive** as a bonus action since I've heard him to be near him?

The same would apply for someone that is invisible can you use the **Aggressive** so that you stay near him by 5 feet, if you make a ready action to trigger if he does move and you heard he move, but while he is invisible.

....

Finally the other question is regarding the **Menacing** trait:
You are trained in the Intimidation skill.

I have never seen anything say , you are trained before on any sourcebook, if we check the bugbear traits it says: **Sneaky**. You are proficient in the Stealth Skill.

So does that mean that no matter what if you use the **Intimidation** skill you will always be successful and don't even need to roll for that check,since you are an Orc?

Comment: Please split your question into two questions:  one about **Menacing** and one about **Aggressive**.

Answer (score 8):

Let's take these one at a time...

**Aggressive**

This allows you to use a Bonus Action to move again (effectively letting you Dash as a bonus action), but you must move *towards* an opponent. (If you started out 50 feet away from the opponent, you must end your movement *at most* 49 feet away from your opponent). It does not mean you have to end the movement adjacent to your opponent, simply that you have to be use this feature to move towards an enemy, rather than maintaining your distance or moving away from them.

This does not have to be moving directly forward. As long as you end your motion closer to your enemy than you started it. For example, if you are 30 feet from an opponent, you could use Aggressive to move 25' in a circle around them, and 5' closer to them...creating a slight spiral in towards your opponent.

This makes that feature more limiting than, say, a Rogue's Cunning Action (Allows a Dash as a bonus action as well), because it restricts it to being a movement towards danger. It prevents you from using it to simply maneuver or run away.

**Menacing**

It means Proficient. That's just a typo. Trained and Proficient mean the same thing. There is no such thing as being so good at a skill that you never, ever fail.

Answer (score -1):

Aggressive:

> As a bonus action, you can move up to your speed toward an enemy of your choice that you can see or hear. You must end this move closer to the enemy than you started.

This is effectively giving you a bonus action dash, provided you use it to move towards your opponent.  It does not specify any distance you must be from your opponent, except that you must end your turn closer to your opponent than you started it.  If you were 90 ft away from your opponent, you can do anything you like with your movement, so long as you are no more than 85ft away from them at the end of your turn.

---

> if I for example make a ready so that when I hear him breathe, and because I've heard him, can I use the Aggressive as a bonus action since I've heard him to be near him?

You cannot ready a bonus action.  Ready is an action you take, where you select an action and a trigger.  If that trigger occurs, you can use your reaction to do your action.  If that trigger does not occur, you lose your action.  (you could still use your reaction to make an attack of opportunity if you readied an action, but that would mean that you are unable to take your readied action if the trigger occurs.

You could get the same result by readying your dash action, to move within 5 ft once your opponent gives themselves away.  However, since using a readied action consumes your reaction, your opponent would be able to leave your threat range without risk of an opportunity attack.

---

Menacing just means you are proficient in intimidation.  You are never guaranteed to be able to succeed 100% of the time.  Imagine if your orc at 2nd level runs into an ancient red dragon, and you try to intimidate.  Should this work?  No.  But it would if you could intimidate 100% of the time.